# Operation priority in Java. (An object instantiates and runs before the GUI is updated?)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I want the GUI to change the title of a button from "Go" to "Working..." before an object is instantiated and actually does the work.  When finished, I want the title of the button to switch back to "Go."

Here's the code:

```
    private class convert implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();

        button.setText("Working...");
        button.setEnabled(false);

        anObject name = new AnObject();
        boolean result = name.methodName(chooser.getSelectedFile(),encoding);

        // A bunch of stuff was here but irrelevant to the question,
        // so it was removed to save room.

        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setText("Go");
    }
```

What actually happens in practise is *name* is instantiated, **methodName** gets called, and THEN the button gets updated on the screen, despite the fact that I have told the VM to change the button title first.

My working theory is, given I have not made this program threaded, this has something to do with operational priority, or internal threading of the JVM, or something...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another possible solution is if your "bunch of stuff irrelevent..." involves displaying another window and you're using a JFrame, use a modal JDialog instead.

Comment: Also please see SwingWorker and AbstractAction solution that I've posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know that you've already accepted a solution, but since you are running into the "frozen gui" syndrome, you most definitely have a threading issue, and invokeLater won't solve your problem. As noted above by extraneon, you need a SwingWorker or some background thread to solve this. Also, I think that this is a good case for use of an AbstractAction rather than an ActionListener. For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Convert extends AbstractAction {
   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 3000; // 3 seconds
   private String enabledText;
   private String disabledText;

   public Convert(String enabledText, String disabledText) {
      super(enabledText);
      this.enabledText = enabledText;
      this.disabledText = disabledText;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object source = e.getSource();
      if (!(source instanceof JButton)) {
         return;
      }
      final JButton button = (JButton) source;
      setButtonEnabled(button, false);
      new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // TODO: long-running code goes here. 
            // Emulated by Thread.sleep(...) 
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void done() {
            setButtonEnabled(button, true);
         }
      }.execute();
   }

   public void setButtonEnabled(JButton button, boolean enabled) {
      if (enabled) {
         button.setText(enabledText);
         button.setEnabled(true);
      } else {
         button.setText(disabledText);
         button.setEnabled(false);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Convert");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ConvertGui());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ConvertGui extends JPanel {
   public ConvertGui() {
      add(new JButton(new Convert("GO", "Working...")));
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(300, 200);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, Yes yes yes! I don't understand why OP thinks the accepted answer is right! It's not!

Comment: If invokeLater is called from the event dispatching thread -- for example, from a JButton's ActionListener -- the doRun.run() will still be deferred until all pending events have been processed. Note that if the doRun.run() throws an uncaught exception the event dispatching thread will unwind (not the current thread).

Comment: I accepted the answer because, when I implemented the solution, it worked.  That said, if there's an issue with it, then it's good to know; as extraneon posted in the comments.

Comment: I didn't say that user802421's answer was wrong, and in fact I up-voted it before making this post. All I'm saying is that if you have a frozen GUI, then you have a threading issue and will require the use of a background thread. Edit: also as Paul Tomblin notes -- 1+ for his answer. :)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I also +1 yours ;) I was responding to Moonbeam, who down vote mine.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, HFoE.  It is definitely helpful and outlines some of the pitfalls new devs can hit.

Comment: why not, your nice examples +1

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels - I've looked at this example closer than earlier on, and while I understand how you've implemented it, I'm trying to figure out *why* you're advocating an AbstractAction rather than an ActionListener.  Perhaps this is inexperience on my part, but given AbstractAction is merely an implementation of the ActionListener interface (and others), and given I don't need to implement any other of the methods, why bother?

Comment: Jeanette (kleopatra), one of the Swing gurus says that you should *always* use Actions rather than ActionListeners, but I don't recall her rationale. My motivation for using Actions is that you're changing the title of the button, and the AbstractAction will do that for you initially (in the super call in my Convert constructor). It also allows you to create a JButton with its behavior and title in one line of code: `add(new JButton(new Convert("GO", "Working...")));`

Comment: Delving deeper into the Swing API, I now see why there's been a controversy over the initial suggestion (and answer I initially accepted.)  It is clearly critical that methodName, regardless of the time taken to do the work, needs to run on a separate thread.  Thanks for the answers and discussion!

Comment: +1 for the uses of SwingWorker, and yes this is the correct approach.

Comment: @Hovercraft You just got 2 "Nice Answer" badges, congrats!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: I wonder how I got those? You shouldn't have, but thanks.

Answer (score 7):

An "ActionPerformed" callback occurs in the event thread, and generally nothing on the GUI will update until it returns.  If you want to update the gui, do something, and then update it again, you will need to update the gui and spawn a thread and return.  The thread will then have to do it's action, and then do a SwingUtilities.invokeLater to update the gui.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It's a nice add-on to the code suggested above, and explains why it's needed. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

```
private class convert implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    final JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();

    button.setText("Working...");
    button.setEnabled(false);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            anObject name = new AnObject();
            boolean result = name.methodName(chooser.getSelectedFile(),encoding);

            // A bunch of stuff was here but irrelevant to the question,
            // so it was removed to save room.

            button.setEnabled(true);
            button.setText("Convert");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please note that this runs in the EDT - if methodName takes a long time your app will freeze. Use a SwingWorker if you have a long-running job, and update the title bar in the done() method.

Comment: That solved it, thank you!  Fairly new to Java, so I'm still learning some of the quirks such as this one.

Comment: @extraneon - thanks also.  Given that the length of operation is dependent on the length of the file methodName is working on, I may need to implement your suggestion.  I wonder how long a "long-running job" is... ;)

Comment: -1, This is just wrong. In this example, you're already in the `EDT` when you use `SwingUtilities`.

Comment: @Moonbeam: If invokeLater is called from the event dispatching thread -- for example, from a JButton's ActionListener -- the doRun.run() will still be deferred until all pending events have been processed. Note that if the doRun.run() throws an uncaught exception the event dispatching thread will unwind (not the current thread).

Comment: @user802421, Edit text, then I will change my vote. MUH BAD! ;]